# Setting index in a state by accesing this.state

Tags: reactjs

It is possible to get state prop inside state in constructor?If not how can I solve this problem?
Here is a example of what I'm trying to achieve. (this isn't working)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var arrOptions = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

    this.state = {
      'arrIndex' : 0,
      'arrOptions' : arrOptions[this.state.arrIndex]
    }
  }
```

Comment: I urge you to take a deep breathe and think about why u need to do this in a constructor ? you can simply do `'arrOptions' : arrOptions[0]` bcoz you are only initialising it and if you need to change may be you need to look at other lifecycle methods then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vague approach can be

```
const state = {
    arrIndex: 0
};
state.arrOptions = arrOptions[state.arrIndex];

this.state = state;
```

If that may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

no, you can not do it in the way you are doing it. 
basically you want to use a variable that has not been initialized.

to solve what you want to achieve you can use this 2 options, after initialization, it will work as always, I think the 2nd option is the best for you.

```js
const arrOptions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const arrIndex = 0;
const state = {
  'arrIndex': arrIndex,
  'arrOptions': arrOptions[arrIndex]
}
console.log(state)
```

```js
const arrOptions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const arrIndex = 0;

let state = {
  'arrIndex': 0,
}

state = {
  ...state,
  'arrOptions': arrOptions[state.arrIndex],

}
console.log(state)
```